# How do I make a google form unrestricted using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-for-education

I am using G Suite for Education.  I have a GAS project that generates a Google Form and emails out a link to it.  I need the form to allow users outside the organization to complete it.  I can't seem to find a way to do it using [Google's reference materials for the Forms service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms).  What would I need to do in in Google Apps Script in order to set the properties of a form so that it can be completed by anyone who has the link to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`setRequireLogin(false)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setrequireloginrequirelogin)

> Sets whether the form requires respondents to log in to an account in the same domain or a subdomain before responding.